# After 13.04, 13.10, 12.10 EOL, is it possible to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.10?

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, 12.10, 13.10, upgrade

I guess, the title can describe the real problem.

I know that upgrading from 12.10 to 14.04 require step by step upgrades from 12.10 to 13.04 to 13.10 to 14.04 LTS.But after the EOL of 12.10, 13.04, 13.10,  I still can't update neither upgrade.
I guess that one of the manual solutions are:

1- Downgrade to 12.04 LTS and then jump to 14.04LTS, is it really possible ?
2- Upgrade to 14.04LTS via DVD, is it possible??

The last question, is there any solution to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 LTS directly that can be expected in the near future??

Thanks for helping

Comment: The last question is unclear.

Comment: @muru: The answers to the question you linked to are focusing on keeping an EOL release, so I don't think it's a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson after setting up old-releases as given in the linked question's answers, you upgrade the normal way (via Update Manager or `do-release-upgrade`). So yes, it is a duplicate.

Comment: i can't update neither upgrade, the update manager still detect 13.04 as the upgrade version, when i try to process the upgrade, it show me a pop up error, no internet connection because it's no more available.

Comment: @muru, thanks for your comment, it was helpful for me to use the old repository

Answer (score 0):

Step by step upgrades are not required as regards non-LTS versions. It's fully possible to upgrade from 12.10 directly to 14.04 LTS. But you should never skip an LTS version.

Downgrading is not a good idea, if at all possible.

*Edit:*

If I was in your situation, I would try:

- `sudo -i gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Replace all occurrences of `quantal` with `trusty` and save
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- Reboot

Comment: It's fully possible to upgrade from 12.10 directly to 14.04 LTS!! How??

Comment: It's *possible*, but not *supported* in any way.

Comment: @Nabilbennasrallah: I just updated my answer with how.

Comment: @saiarcot895: I know it's not officially supported. However, since LTS to LTS upgrades are supported, migration code needs to be kept until next LTS.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: If you just change the distros in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you won't get any "migration code"; that code is downloaded only through the use of `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: @saiarcot895: I think of migration code in the packages, e.g. in maintenance scripts. What kind of code do you have in mind?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: ah, that code. I thought you were referring to some code that determines what packages should be upgraded at all costs or something. At any rate, the maintenance scripts tend to remain the same across versions.

Comment: Thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson , i'll be trying your solution.

Comment: This solution is not really working,i can upgrade the 12.10 OS to 14.04 LTS, but some troubles are running during the upgrade, so I have to run "apt-get install-f " but still have a problem after dist-upgrade. No desktop and even shell window can't be opened. It's seems like it's not the right way to do so.

Comment: @Nabilbennasrallah: Can you say anything more about the nature of the problems? Did you reboot? (If you fail making it work, I'm going to delete the answer.)

Comment: I already did the same steps and I had a kind of error when running  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade so i was obliged to run apt-get install -f so i can run the rest f commands and complete the upgrade. Now the system boots on 14.04 LTS but without desktop. I was trying to reinstall ubuntu-desktop,but even the shell window can't be opened. I will be trying to review this method, if there is any suggestion it will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Nabilbennasrallah: `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` might contain useful guidance. Maybe you could edit your question and add the contents of that file.

Comment: I was trying this on a virtual machine I can't get the access to recovery mode to discover this file's content.